# Parsing a variable (Php or C++)

Tags: php, c++

I encountered a question in a programming exam earlier this morning.

It had this variable named `strParse = A101619915589.2E76885B66182;`

The question instructed to separate each of the following content of the variable into their own variables

```
strParse = A 10161991 5589.2 E 76885 B 66182;

Code = A
Date = 10161991
variable1 = 5589.2
Code2 = E
variable2 = 76885
Code3 = B
variable3 = 66182
```

That's pretty much the paper wants me to do but I really had no idea how to do it.

Comment: C++ or PHP? Pick one. They are _completely_ different languages.

Comment: And is the value supposed to be a string? Are there rules for how it's supposed to be split up into those new variables?

Comment: if it's php the simple regex with preg_match()

Comment: or maybe a bunch of `substr`. If you can't figure out this simple problem, you deserve to fail the exam because you've been asleep in class.

Comment: I read it as just a simple problem: find A, find the date in a known format, put all characters into another variable until you find E, put all characters into another variable until you find B, put all remaining characters into another variable.

Comment: Do it in PHP please. Thanks

FYI, I never encountered this during my life in college. Sorry if I did not study this part but I did pass the exam anyway.. This was just one of the problems.

Comment: I just want to understand. Well anyway, thanks for asking and then making a fool out of me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php, you could do:

```
 $arr = explode(" ", $strparse); 

 $code = $arr[0];
 $date = $arr[1]; 
 $variable1 = arr[2]; 
 ... and so on.
```

In C++, you could use for example `strinstream`:

```
 stringstream ss(strParse);
 string code, code2, code3
 string date;
 double variable1, variable2, variable3;

 ss >> code >> date >> variable1 >> code2 >> variable2 >> code3 >> variable3;
```

There are certainly at least a dozen other ways in both languages, but this should give you a starting point.

Comment: The variable contained no spaces. Explode wasn't a good idea back then. 

I think I understand what you mean in your C++ code.

Comment: If there are no spaces, then you have to use something like `substr` and known lengths, if lengths are not known, use while loops to determine the size of the elements. It's not overly complicated, but not entirely trivial either. Much better to have separators!

Comment: Yeah. That question really gave me a headache, I'm lost without internet. Thank you very much man!

Answer (score 1):

The string will be always have the same number of characters?

Code will be AA instead of A etc?

EDIT

You can use this in PHP (onyl if numbers are standard)

```
Code = $strParse[0];
Date = substr($strParse, 1, 8);
variable1 = substr($strParse, 10, 6);
Code2 = substr($strParse, 16, 1);
variable2 = substr($strParse, 17, 5);
Code3 = substr($strParse, 22, 1);
variable3 = substr($strParse, 23, 5);
```

Comment: This is a question, not an answer. Wait until you get rep 40 then you can post comments.

Comment: im glad that i helped you m8 :)